# Amadeus Flight Low-fare Search - Airport coordinates

Tags: amadeus

When I get schedule data between two airports, I'd like to show the flight's route on a map, especially if it has connections.

To reach this, I'd need to know each affected airports' GPS coordinates.

Is it possible to get them in the dictionaries->locations object next to the name?

If that's not possible in the same request, how should I get the GPS coordinates of the affected airports based on the IATA code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the coordinates by using the [Airport &  City Search API](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/airport-and-city-search)

It comes with 2 endpoints:

The first one allows you to search directly by keyword (either an airport or a city or both). In the response you get the geo-location.

London for example:

> https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/reference-data/locations?subType=AIRPORT,CITY&keyword=london

The second endpoint allows you to retrieve information for a dedicated city of airport based on an IATA code. For example, if you want to retrieve the information about the airport of **LHR** you can do:

> https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/reference-data/locations/ALHR

The **A** before **LHR** is to specify that it's the IATA of an airport (as sometimes airports and cities can have the same IATA).
If you wanted to get the information for the city of **NYC** you will have to do:

> https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/reference-data/locations/CNYC

This time, **C** is used before the IATA code to specify that you want to get information for the IATA code of the city of **NYC**.